# save text file and display its content on the browser

Tags: python

If the following script.py writes "some text here" to output.txt file, my URL will be `http://my_name/script.py`. My question is, how can I read the output.txt as soon as (right after) the following function creates it, so that my URL reads like `http://my_name/output.txt`.
Many thanks in advance.

```
#------ script.py -------
def write_txt(){
   f=('./output.txt', 'w')
   f.write("some text here")
}
```

Comment: You realize that `..` will be outside the document root, right?

Comment: Thanks, Ignacio I made that change :)

Comment: `from __future__ import braces`

Answer (score 0):

try webbrowser lib.

```
import webbrowser

myurl = "file:///mydir/output.txt"
webbrowser.open(myurl)
```

However:

> Note that on some platforms, trying to
>   open a filename using this function,
>   may work and start the operating
>   system’s associated program.

That is: your file will probably be open in your default text editor (p.e. notepad). A possible solution is to give a custom extension to your file (p.e. output.url) and to associate the extension to your browser (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on various factors, like OS and webserver used.

Pipe the output to the browser specifying a correct content-type, or, given you script writes to an accessible location, issue a HTTP redirect code pointing to that location.